# Update tabela com campo XML e em bancos diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Tenho dois bancos ***SQL SERVER 2012*** instalados no servidor A e no servidor B, preciso inserir e depois fazer um *Update* na tabela do servidor B via ***linkedServer*** pelo servidor A, porém nessas tabelas possuem campos ***XML***, não necessariamente estou atualizando esse campo, mas toda vez que tento fazer qualquer atualização nos demais campos me retorna a msg:

> ```
> "Msg 9514, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. Xml data type is not supported
> in distributed queries"
> ```

Alguém teria alguma *solução/exemplo* que eu possa utilizar via ***LinkedServer*** ou até uma que eu possa trabalhar com tabelas com ***XML*** em dois servidores com ***SQL SERVER 2012?***

Comment: Em aberto até hoje, desde 2006: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/247204/tables-with-xml-columns-cannot-be-queried-using-distributed-llinked-server-queries // Há duas soluções de contorno propostas pela Microsoft; avalie se alguma delas te atende.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, com ela consegui identificar outro exemplo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495719/querying-a-linked-sql-server&usg=ALkJrhir2B3wCCcO6Sx9DZySQcZgOTV0LA